# Is there a way to symbolically denote a Homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, group-homomorphism

The First Isomorphism Theorem is (I think) the first to explicitly Declare a group homomorphism:

> Given groups $(G,*),(H,\circ)$ (Or just $G,H$). If $f: G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism then:
>
> 1. $\ker(f) \triangleleft G$
> 2. $G / \ker(f) \cong \operatorname{im}(f) \leq H$

There is quite a lot of information contained in the few relations encoded in this first consequence (and the proof) of the property of being a group homomorphism.

My main question:

Given $G,H$: Does the collection of all homomorphisms $G \to H$ qualify as a set, generally speaking? In any case, is there an abbreviation?

Related secondary questions:

1. There exist a homomorphism with domain $G$ and kernel $K \triangleleft G$ for each $K \triangleleft G$. Does every $K$ correspond to a target group (up to isomorphism)?
2. Do all groups isomorphic to $G/K$ correspond to a homomorphism with domain $G$?
3. What is the valid way (if any) of stating "$f \in Grp(G,H)$" ?

Comment: For 2) If a group $(N,\circ)$ is isomorphic to $G/K$ where $K\triangleleft G$, then there must exist a bijection $f: G/K \to N$ such that $f(x*w)=f(x)\circ f(w)$ with $x,w \in G/K$. So yes.

Comment: $G / K \neq G $

Comment: True but there is always a homomorphism $h: G\to G/K$. So what does that mean for the composite function $f\circ h$ or $f(h(x))$?

Comment: I've seen the dotted-arrow notation, as in $f : G \ \overset{\longrightarrow}{.}  \ H$, in more than a few places to denote homomorphisms. Some texts place the dot on top of the arrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$0)$ The collection of all *set functions* $G\to H$ is a set (since $G$ and $H$ are both sets), and since the collection of all *homomorphisms* $G\to H$ is just a subset of this, it is certainly a set as well. From the point of view of category theory, if we let $\bf{Grp}$ denote the category of groups, then you can denote this set by $\hom_{\bf{Grp}}(G,H)$, or $\operatorname{Mor}_{\bf{Grp}}(G,H)$. If the category is clear from context we'd usually just write $\hom(G,H)$.

$1)$ Yes. If $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $G/K$ is a group, and $K$ is the kernel of the "natural" projection homomorphism $G\to G/K$, which sends $g\mapsto gK$.

$2)$ If $H$ is isomorphic to $G/K$, then you can choose an isomorphism $\varphi:G/K\to H$, and take the composition

$$G\to G/K\overset{\varphi}{\to}H,$$

where the first map is again the natural projection, to get a homomorphism $G\to H$.

$3)$ Yes, going back to "$0$", we can just write $f\in\hom_{\bf{Grp}}(G,H)$, or $f\in\hom(G,H)$.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. I was trying to wrap my head around what on earth Dror was trying to get at with $f \in grp(G,H)$. Thanks

Comment: yeah nvm I was reading the times wrong.

Comment: The morphism for the category of groups is group-homomorphism, and as I read and also makes sense you can write $C(A,B)$.

Comment: @Dror Yes that's correct! That's a valid notation in category theory to write $\mathscr C(A,B)$ as well if $\mathscr C$ is the category. It would probably look a bit odd to write $\mathbf{Grp}(G,H)$ in most contexts, but it wouldn't be wrong